# Extra enclosing quotes in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe whose column shows extra quotes that enclose some of the records. Let's say col_a is a column which has multiple entries like ABC, DEF etc.

Some of the rows have ABC showing up as 'ABC' while others are present as ABC. Dataframe is sourced from a csv file. I opened the csv file manually and do not see any occurrences with quotes in the data.

I tried processing the data using str.replace("/'",'') function to remove single quotes but no luck. I am using this dataframe to group the data and publish results that calculates sum and other metrics. Since the quotes are additional characters, my aggregations are being broken down for same attribute value.

Is there a better way to handle these extra characters

Comment: please provide your input dataframe & the expected dataframe, that is much easier to understand & work with. You can directly paste the contents from excel into the text box.

Comment: You can use `df['col'] = df['col'].str.strip("'")`

Comment: realized its an issue with source data and worked out a diff solution

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to replace

```
df.replace ({'\'': ''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```